# How to pull attribute details from btnclass webscraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, excel-2016

I'm currently trying to pull specific information from within a BTnClass element on a webpage.

the specific button and preceding element details are:

```
<div class="m-t-sm">

<button class="btnLink " id="viewClientRecord_1-00001"
type="button" data-url="/?mtoken=itg999="><span class="text">View referral summary and client record
<span class="offscreen">&nbsp;for CLIENT NAME</span></span></button>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the data for

```
data-url
```

To add further complexity, there are 200,000 client records and the ID for the Btn Class is unique to each client, so I cannot rely on ID for this to work (having said that I also tried to use ID and failed.

I've tried the following options:

The unique element

```
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = html.getElementById("viewClientRecord_1-00001")(0).Children(0).getAttribute("data-url")(0).innerHTML
```

The top div class

```
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = html.getElementsByclassname("Cardf-row")(0).Children(0).getAttribute("data-url")(0).innerHTML
```

The preceding class

```
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = html.getElementsByclassname("m-t-sm")(0).Children(0).getAttribute("data-url")(0).innerHTML

Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = html.getElementsByclassname("m-t-sm")(0).getAttribute("data-url")(0).innerHTML

Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = html.getElementsByclassname("m-t-sm")(0).getAttribute("data-url").innerHTML

Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = html.getElementsByclassname("btnlink ")(0).getAttribute("data-url").innerHTML
```

NO matter what I try, i cannot get getAttribute("data-url") to pick up anything :(

edit. Updated to GetElementsByClassName

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection, and it's `get​Elements​ByClass​Name`, not `get​Elements​ByClass`.

Comment: Sorry, I have used getelementsbyclassname in my actual code: getElementsByClassName("cardrow cf")(ClientPageRecord).getElementsByClassName

Comment: I think we can improve on this. How many pages are you visiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I didn't inspect your line `html.getElementById("viewClientRecord_1-00001")(0).Children(0)`, I assume it's correct with the exception of the index number that is illegal on `.getElementByID()`.

The `.getAttribute()` function doesn't return a collection. If it did, it would likely follow the rest of `HTMLDocument`'s naming convention and would have appended an `s` to make it `.getAttributes()`. This means you can't append an index number to it as you did with `.getAttribute("data-url")(0)`.

Also, `getAttribute()` returns a string. Strings do not contain an `.innerText` property. You need to remove `.innerText` and just return the result from the function `getAttribute`. This brings you to the final result of:

```
Sheets("Results").Range("A" & ClientRowNumber).Value = _
     html.getElementById("viewClientRecord_1-00001").Children(0).getAttribute("data-url")
```

Comment: K.Davis, you are on the money, by removing innertext innerhtml etc it worked immediately!